# Amazon S3 and heroku NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, heroku, amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-s3

First of all a brief overview:
I have a iphone app and a Java PLay(2.1.1) framework application running on heroku and I also have Amazon S3 to store some images uploaded. 
So basically the iPhone app sends an image to the java app and then that transfers it to S3 once uploaded, I then have a page which you can view that uploaded image.

Now the problem is that when I first deploy the application everything works as it should but after a few days the connection seems to fail to S3 and I just get a Internal server error:

```
@6ekb4bp0a - Internal server error, for (GET) [/view/51c0b5d3e4b082764a289889] ->
2013-06-20T08:59:39.318089+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-20T08:59:38.727484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/view/51c0b5d3e4b082764a289889 host=myapp.co.uk fwd="---.---.---.--" dyno=web. connect=1ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=1941
2013-06-20T08:59:39.422984+00:00 app[web.1]: play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: method <init>()V not found]]
2013-06-20T08:59:39.523670+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:39.621627+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:39.722105+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:144) [play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:39.819446+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:140) [play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:39.916774+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-        2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.015921+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.113516+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: method <init>()V not found
2013-06-20T08:59:40.211257+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.mvc.Security$AuthenticatedAction.call(Security.java:47) ~[play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.317848+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:74) ~[play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.416593+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:73) ~[play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.514600+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:420) ~[play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.612653+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.710218+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
2013-06-20T08:59:40.809756+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: method <init>()V not found
2013-06-20T08:59:40.907239+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createThreadSafeClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:26) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
2013-06-20T08:59:41.006986+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:95) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
2013-06-20T08:59:41.104293+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:118) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
2013-06-20T08:59:41.204123+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:65) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
2013-06-20T08:59:41.302700+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:298) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
2013-06-20T08:59:41.409163+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:280) ~[aws-java-sdk-1.4.2.1.jar:na]
```

This is happening when I am trying to retrieve the image from S3 using this code (well I am pretty sure it is as this is the only place I use S3 on the view):

```
    public static String generateS3Url(String filename, int minutes) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        Date expDate = cal.getTime();
        try {
            BasicAWSCredentials cre = new BasicAWSCredentials(Play.application().configuration().getString("amazons3.accessKey"), Play.application().configuration().getString("amazons3.secretKey"));
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(cre);
            String url = s3.generatePresignedUrl(BUCKET_NAME, filename, expDate, HttpMethod.GET).toString();
            return url;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As you can see it creates a temporary url to a image name supplied, this works absolutley fine locally too using the exact same details and on the server for a certain amount of time. Do you think it needs to be restarted every so often?

I hope this is enough information,

Thanks if you can help,

Rich

** EDIT **
Build.scala dependencies

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
  )
```

Comment: Is it the full stacktrace?

Comment: yes for this specific error.

Comment: Can you show the dependencies in Build.scala?

Comment: Yup sure: val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
  )

Comment: Don't you use the AWS JDK?
I use this dependence "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.3.11"

Comment: Aha Thanks that seems to have worked now, I never knew you had to include that as it seemed to work ok without it... still getting used to play framework